# Asp:Label obtaining value from HiddenField on localhost but not on live version

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am developping a website in asp.net. On one of the pages, I initialise a repeater containing, among other elements, multiple HiddenFields.

Outside of the repeater, during my Pageload, I initialize Labels with Text values taken from those HiddenFields, in specific Repeater items. Testing in localhost lead to no problems. However on the live version I noticed one of the Labels didn't display any value, although the HiddenField linked to it did hold the wanted value.

Here is a sample of code from the concerned page :

aspx :

```
<form id="detailForm" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManagerGlobal" runat="server" EnableScriptGlobalization="true" />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Code d'Activation</th>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="L_Code_Activation" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Dernière action </th>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="L_Libelle_Actuel" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP_KSS" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table>
                <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterContainer" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Date de Requète
                            </th>
                            <th>Action
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="HF_Id_kss_container" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("id_kss_container") %>' />
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="CodeActivationHidden" Value='<%# Eval("CodeActivation") %>' />
                                <asp:Label ID="L_DateRequest" runat="server" Text='<%# LaDate(Eval("DateRequest")) %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="LibelleHidden" Value='<%# (LOperation(Eval("Libelle"))) %>' />
                                <asp:Label ID="L_Libelle" runat="server" Text='<%#(LOperation(Eval("Libelle"))) %>' />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

(Please note : the methods "LOperation" and "LaDate" simply change the format of the value returned by "Eval". They shouldn't affect the rest of the code.)

.aspx.cs :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        initRepeaterContainer(); //
        initLabels();
    }

protected void initLabels()
    {
        // L_Libelle_Actuel
        Label lblLibelleActuel = (Label)detailForm.FindControl("L_Libelle_Actuel");
        HiddenField hfLibelleHidden = (HiddenField)(RepeaterContainer.Items[0].FindControl("LibelleHidden"));
        lblLibelleActuel.Text = hfLibelleHidden.Value;

        // L_Code_Activation
        Label lblCodeActivation = (Label)detailForm.FindControl("L_Code_Activation");
        HiddenField hfCodeActivationHidden = (HiddenField)(RepeaterContainer.Items[(RepeaterContainer.Items.Count)-1].FindControl("CodeActivationHidden"));
        lblCodeActivation.Text = hfCodeActivationHidden.Value;
    }
```

Here's the problem : when running in localhost, the page works fine, and both labels here show the expected values. However, when running on the live website, only the "L_Libelle_Actuel" Label shows the correct value.

The "L_Code_Activation" Label only translates to an empty span with id="L_Code_Activation". The weird thing is, when inspecting the resulting page, I can see that the expected value is present in the Hiddenfield that's linked to this Label.

Does anyone know why this problem happens, and why it does not happen on localhost? I've searched far and wide, but haven't seen anyone with the same issue, and haven't been able to reproduce it in a local environment. If you do know what is causing it, do you know how to fix it?

Thanks, have a great day.

EDIT: Forgot to say it, although it seems like a minor thing, but I get no error or warning when looking at my navigator's dev console. It's like the Label was never initialized.

EDIT 2: here are what the result looks like. I replaced the actual data with "[value]" as it is sensible information.

[On localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRRew.png)

[On live website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiYlb.png)

Here is what the generated label and hiddenfield look like in both cases. Once again I replaced the expected data with "[value]".

Localhost :

```
<span id="L_Code_Activation">[value]</span> 
...
<input type="hidden" name="RepeaterContainer$ctl01$CodeActivationHidden" id="RepeaterContainer_CodeActivationHidden_0" value="[value]">
```

Live Website :

```
<span id="L_Code_Activation"></span>
...
<input type="hidden" name="RepeaterContainer$ctl01$CodeActivationHidden" id="RepeaterContainer_CodeActivationHidden_0" value="[value]">
```

EDIT 3: The problem actually comes from the server in itself, and not the code. I should have checked there first, sorry about that...

Comment: Since you're retrieving the code activation value differently than you are retrieving the libelle value, I'm wondering if this could be data related. The code activation is being retrieved from the last repeater item, could it be that locally you have less records than out live? Can you show us the rendered output?

Comment: Hi! I don't see straight away anything wrong in the code, though I have a few questions to clarify the issue. How many items are you databinding to the repeater? You are taking the actual-value from the first row and the activation-value from the last row? Also you are not checking Page.IsPostBack in page-load, is that by design, do you want to databind again on every postback?

Comment: @Gabe I tried retrieving the information from the first, last or any other item of the repeater. Nothing changes, so this isn't the source of the problem.

Comment: @Esko the amount of item data-bound varies, from a single entry up to 6 or more. I do want to databind on every postback, reason why I didn't check for a postback in my Pageload.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make an ajax request onpageload? Updating data on server side is not always a great idea.

So I suggest you this : 
- On your aspx.cs file, add a function which inits a model and returns a JSON flow of the model.
- Add in your js file, an ajax request which will calls your function (the aspx.cs). By the result of it, you should be able to refresh your components.

You can refer with this : https://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ajax.asp

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but that might be because I've never used Ajax before. If I got it right, I should make an Ajax request to call the codebehind function that initializes my Labels? (initLabel)

What's the difference between doing that and simply calling my function in the pageload method?

Comment: ASP has a page life cycle, which initialize your objects at page load. During this time, the page shows up its components so it can be difficult on page load to initalize your components (refering to this : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_life_cycle). That's why I suggested you to pass by ajax request. And yes, you got it. The ajax request will call a function in your code behind file (aspx.cs). So, to be clear, when you call your function in ajax request, you will have to get the json result and set the values of your labels

Comment: I don't think the WebForms page life cycle is going to come into play at all with this issue. There's no reason this shouldn't be working and is in fact working on his local machine.

Comment: The other option is that his IIS is too old to load his components. At least, Ajax request will surely resolve his issue

Answer (score 0):

Actually please ignore this question. The problem does not come from the code, but from the server in itself. I just didn't check the source of the problem at first, sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what was it?

Comment: I was not the one to setup the server, I was just told where to put the files for it. I made many changes to those files, and the server recompiled the codebehind files at every change so I took it for granted. Today I made more modifications, including some to those Labels, and for some reason the server didn't recompile the codebehind files, keeping the old version from yesterday. I'm dumb, sorry once again.